# How to start IIS application pools which are stopped only for websites which has "Started" status using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, iis, application-pool

does anyone can point me direction how I can start IIS (7/8) application pools which are stopped only for websites which has "Started" status using Powershell (so no starting app pool for their connected application/websites which has Stopped state)?

Scenario1:
Stopped app pool
Started website

START app pool

Scenario2:
Stopped app pool
Stopped website

DO NOTHING

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what it is unclear here. I'm looking for a way to start using Powershell Windows IIS web server application pools which are stopped but only if applications which are using this app pools have started status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand the downvotes too. However, you can try this:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

gci IIS:\Sites |
     where state -eq 'Started' | 
     select -ExpandProperty applicationPool | 
     % { Start-WebAppPool $_ }
```

It seems like you don't have to check whether the applicationPool is already started, but you can adopt the script and check the status using the [Get-WebAppPoolState](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=268827) cmdlet if you think its necessary.

Comment: Great. It looks like I will have to use also Get-WebAppPoolState because of website number runned on IIS server but I will probably manage to do that on my own. Thanks